# Set of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set

$\mathcal{S} = \{(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \times \mathbb{C}^{n} \mid \mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{y} = ||\mathbf{y}||^{2}_{2}\}$.
Does $\mathcal{S}$ a set of measure zero in $\mathbb{C}^{n} \times \mathbb{C}^{n}$?

Comment: What dimension has the set?

Comment: @DanielFischer are you implying that $S$ is a linear subspace of $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, I'm implying that it is a submanifold. (It's actually an affine subspace, but that's more than we need to see the measure.)

Comment: @DanielFischer The set $\{(x,y):(x-y)y = 0\}$ is not an affine subspace of $\Bbb F^n$ (it is the union of two, but not closed under affine combinations), nor is it a [submanifold](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138562/is-the-union-of-two-manifolds-a-manifold).  Though, as the other answers suggest, this does not change the intuitive answer to the problem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Duh. I thought of fixed $y$ when I wrote that. Of course the union over all $y$ isn't an affine subspace.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah, cool! That's a neat way to look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write out the equation in components and take the real and imaginary components of those constituent equations, you see that the set cuts out a proper real variety in $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \times \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, which thus has measure zero.

Edit: In fact, you don't need to expand the equation at all: it's enough to see that (1) the equation is polynomial (in fact, quadratic) in the real and imaginary parts of the coordinates, and (2) that there is a point not in the set, say, $\mathbf{0}$ and $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I have another question: Have all real varieties $\mathbf{V} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f_{i}(\mathbf{x}) = 0, 1 \leq i \leq m\}$ measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Yes, except, obviously, for $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself, which is the zero set of the zero polynomial. There is a natural topology on $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ called the *Zariski Topology*, in which the closed sets are precisely the varieties, and one can show that nonempty open sets in this topology (namely, complements of varieties) are open and dense in the standard topology.

Answer (score 2):

Your set $S$ is a level set of a smooth function $f: \mathbb C^{n\times n }\to \mathbb C$,
with 
$$
f(x,y)=x^Ty-x^Tx,
$$
and hence is has measure zero.

In fact $S$ can be viewed as a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^{2n\times 2n}$ of co-dimension $2$.

Comment: Yiorgos, the rank of $Tf$ is zero at $(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{0})$, so this set can be singular at the origin. In fact this is the case; for $n = 1$, $S$ is the union of the (complex) hyperplanes $x = 0$ and $x = y$, which intersect at $0$.